# IOS - Scale background image to different screen sizes and put label on fixed position on it

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first iOS app and I'm using Swift.
I have an image that I would like to place as background image to screen,
I've set its mode to Scale to fill(to fill the all screen) and its constraints (Top, Left, Right, Bottom ) to:0 then check Aspect Ratio. My Problem is on my background there is specific parts I have to put labels in it to view some text. After setting constraints to labels to be on those fixed position and running app on different devices labels aren't in its places. I searched on how to use Auto Layout and how to set constraints to labels and background images but I don't reach any helpful result.
Any help please.
[This image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhCkY.png)

Comment: Since different devices will have different screen sizes so your labels position are likely to change on different devices. A simple solution would be to modify the image itself with required label content within that image and use this modified image in the app.

Comment: please post screenshot explaining the problem.

Comment: @Meet, The idea of my app is that When users swipe right or left the text in labels changes. Labels don't contain fixed text.

Comment: @Shubhank, I edit my question. You will find an image in the link

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to synchronize image that stretches and labels.
You can use your image not as background, but as just part of UI elements. You should make constraint between this imageView and your labels. For background you can use another imageView.

Comment: It works but there is much white spaces around the image specially when preview it on IPad and My interface doesn't look good.

Comment: Ok. Try in such a manner: ddd UIView, which will be the container View for ImageView and Labels.
Add contraints top, bottom from container View to main View of ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very feasible solution to your problem.
1) Take a cutout of exact size from the designer as for now i have cropped your image.
2) Place an imageView in the centre,add image to the imageView and just put two constraints i.e horizontally in container and vertically in container and simply use update frames. What it does is sets the imageView to exact size of the image.
3) Now place a label on top left corner of the imageView, doing right click on the label drag the mouse in downwards direction from label to imageView add select leading from the options.Again right click the mouse and drag it towards right from label to imageView and choose top, after that simply update frames.

Label and imageView both works completely fine on even two constraints. Now your label will always be in exact position, and now you can place rest other cutouts with respect to the main imageView in the center.[image: Your label gets set in exact place in just 4 constraints]

Comment: What issue you are facing exactly ?

Comment: For image view I add 0,0,0,0 constraints according to view, it's mode scale to fill and for label do what you said exactly but label isn't in the place I want on the image because Image stretched according to the screen size and label position doesn't match stretching of image.

Comment: Share me the image and screen to be done at gupta.ishika.ishika@gmail.com, i will provide you a sample app with your requirement.